# Different Date format in predicate when comparing against a date or datetime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, type-conversion

I have the following query:

```
SELECT  CAST(MyDateTimeCol AS DATE) AS MyDate,
        Col1,
        Col2
FROM    MyTable
WHERE   MyDateTimeCol >= '2019-11-25' AND MyDateTimeCol < '2019-11-26'
```

Which gives me the error

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

If I change the WHERE clause to

```
WHERE   MyDateTimeCol >= '2019-25-11' AND MyDateTimeCol < '2019-26-11'
```

This works.

However, I change my original query to the equivalent (performance issues aside)

```
SELECT  CAST(MyDateTimeCol AS DATE) AS MyDate,
        Col1,
        Col2
FROM    MyTable
WHERE   CAST(MyDateTimeCol AS DATE) = '2019-11-25'
```

The query works without any errors

Why does casting the `datetime` as a `date` mean I have to use a different `Datetime` format in the predicate?

Comment: Please read [What date/time literal formats are LANGUAGE and DATEFORMAT safe?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166771/what-date-time-literal-formats-are-language-and-dateformat-safe) by Aaron Bertrand and [Using Date and Time Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms180878(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) from books online. Key is `The ISO 8601 format does not depend on any of your local settings and is an international standard`.

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, you compare a datetime to a string. The format for that string is YYYY-MM-DD, meaning that the login's language will determine what is to be interpreted and month vs day. You seems to be in the UK, I assume a British login. Check out for instance sp_helplanguage you'll see how the "separated" datetime format is interpreted for various languages.

The "separated" format is, btw, not to be confused with the ISO 8601 format, which is YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS (the letter T is what makes the difference).

When you cast the column to the date type, you no longer compare the string to datetime, you compare it to the more modern date type. This *will* always interpret the "separated" format as ymd, and is in other words *not* dependent on the login's language.

If you were using the more modern datetime2, btw, you wouldn't have the problem in the first place, since it is handled as date.

See my datetime article for further elaboration: https://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes .